# Date format in C++

Tags: c++, string

This is my class

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>

class Date {
 public:
  /**
  * @brief default constructor
  */
  Date();

  /**
  * @brief constructor with arguments
  */
  Date(int t_year, int t_month, int t_day, int t_hour, int t_minute);

  /**
  * @brief constructor with a string
  */
  Date(const std::string &dateString);
  /**
  * @brief return the year of a Date
  * @return   a integer indicate the year of a date
  */
  int getYear(void) const;

  /**
  * @brief set the year of a date
  * @param a integer indicate the new year of a date
  */
  void setYear(const int t_year);

  /**
  * @brief return the month of a Date
  * @return   a integer indicate the month of a date
  */
  int getMonth(void) const;

  /**
  * @brief set the month of a date
  * @param a integer indicate the new month of a date
  */
  void setMonth(const int t_month);

  /**
  * @brief return the day of a Date
  * @return   a integer indicate the day of a date
  */
  int getDay(void) const;

  /**
  * @brief set the day of a date
  * @param a integer indicate the new day of a date
  */
  void setDay(const int t_day);

  /**
  * @brief return the hour of a Date
  * @return   a integer indicate the hour of a date
  */
  int getHour(void) const;

  /**
  * @brief set the hour of a date
  * @param a integer indicate the new hour of a date
  */
  void setHour(const int t_hour);

  /**
  * @brief return the minute of a Date
  * @return   a integer indicate the minute of a date
  */
  int getMinute(void) const;

  /**
  * @brief set the minute of a date
  * @param a integer indicate the new minute of a date
  */
  void setMinute(const int t_minute);

  /**
  *   @brief check whether the date is valid or not
  *   @return the bool indicate valid or not
  */
  static bool isValid(const Date &t_date);

  /**
  * @brief convert a string to date, if the format is not correct return
  * 0000-00-00/00:00
  * @return a date
  */
  static Date stringToDate(const std::string &t_dateString);

  /**
  * @brief convert a date to string, if the date is invalid return
  * 0000-00-00/00:00
  */
  static std::string dateToString(const Date &t_date);

  /**
  *  @brief overload the assign operator
  */
  Date &operator=(const Date &t_date);

  /**
  * @brief check whether the CurrentDate is equal to the t_date
  */
  bool operator==(const Date &t_date) const;

  /**
  * @brief check whether the CurrentDate is  greater than the t_date
  */
  bool operator>(const Date &t_date) const;

  /**
  * @brief check whether the CurrentDate is  less than the t_date
  */
  bool operator<(const Date &t_date) const;

  /**
  * @brief check whether the CurrentDate is  greater or equal than the t_date
  */
  bool operator>=(const Date &t_date) const;

  /**
  * @brief check whether the CurrentDate is  less than or equal to the t_date
  */
  bool operator<=(const Date &t_date) const;

 private:
  int m_year;
  int m_month;
  int m_day;
  int m_hour;
  int m_minute;
};

#endif
```

So i get 3 constructors, 1)default 2) with arguments 3) with string.

In third one, i get a string of a date in format(example) : 2018-10-25/14:00(ie. yy-mm-dd/hh:mm). So i need to store these values into my private variables (m_year,m_month,m_day,m_hour,m_minute). Its kinda like i need to somehow read this string format, detect what is what and store it, but how ?

Comment: [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::string date  = "2018-05-07/09:00";
    int t_year, t_month, t_day, t_hour, t_minute;

    sscanf_s(date.c_str(), "%4d-%2d-%2d/%2d:%2d",
        &t_year,
        &t_month,
        &t_day,
        &t_hour,
        &t_minute);

    std::cout << t_year << 
        "-" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << t_month << 
        "-" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << t_day <<
        "/" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << t_hour << 
        ":" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << t_minute << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2018-05-07/09:00
```

Note that for `sscanf_s` you need to use a C-string. Therefore, you first need to convert `date` with `c_str()`. If you run the program under Linux, then use `sscanf` instead of `sscanf_s`.

Comment: hi, could you write the full version of ur code. It seems like i made some mistakes when i did it by myself

Comment: Sure, I have posted a full example. Are you running the program under Linux? Then use `sscanf` instead of `sscanf_s`.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult task to get calendar dates and times to be validated and manipulated correctly. Actually only few people will succeed to do it correctly and efficiently.

So avoid researching that on your own if possible. In C++ use [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) for working with dates and times. If you need parsing and formatting then use [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that is built upon `<chrono>`. The [Boost.Date_Time](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/date_time.html) is also option, but weaker in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expression to solve this problem. Like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input("2018-10-25/14:00");

    regex format("(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)/(\\d+):(\\d++)");

    smatch result;
    int year, month, day, hour, minute;
    if (regex_match(input, result, format))
    {
        year = stoi(result[1].str());
        month = stoi(result[2].str());
        day = stoi(result[3].str());
        hour = stoi(result[4].str());
        minute = stoi(result[5].str());
    }

    cout << year << "-" << month << "-" << day 
        << "/" << hour << ":" << minute << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

More information: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Comment: what about the format, i understood about regex, but cant find a way to make the output as a given format. It must be 2016-01-23/12:05 but not 2016-1-23/12:5